# Adding data to charts.js dynamically from tables

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

First I would like to count occurrences using two JSON arrays:

Question table as answer choices:

```
{["Answer1","Answer2","Answer3","Answer4", ...]}
```

Results table as answers:

```
{["Answer1","Answer1","Answer1","Answer1","Answer1","Answer2","Answer2","Answer2"]}
```

I need to figure out how to count them dynamically

```
{ 
  Answer1: 5,
  Answer2: 3,
  Answer3: 0,
  Answer4: 0
}
```

Then I also would need to pass them into this Charts.js (labels and data)

```
data: {
  labels: ['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3', 'Answer4', ...]
  datasets: [{
    label: ': votes',
    data: ["5", "3", "0", "0", ...],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,102,204,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,102,204,1)',
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
},
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return the data you need for ChartJS:

```js
function getCountData(choices, results) {
  var counts = {};
  var data = [];

  choices.forEach(function(c) {
    counts[c] = 0;
  });

  results.forEach(function(r) {
    counts[r] += 1;
  });

  Object.keys(counts).forEach(function(c) {
    data.push(counts[c]);
  });

  return data;
}

var choices = ['Answer1', 'Answer2', 'Answer3', 'Answer4', 'Answer5'];
var results = ["Answer1", "Answer1", "Answer1", "Answer1", "Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer2", "Answer2"];

console.log(getCountData(choices, results));
```

You can use the above function with ChartJS like this:

```
data: {
  labels: choices,
  datasets: [{
    label: ': votes',
    data: getCountData(choices, results),
    // ...
  }]
},
```

Comment: Others worked also, but this is the one that I used.

Answer (score 0):

This fonction can count your answers based on your answers and results :

```
function dynamicCounter(answers,results){
    return answers.map( (a) => {
        var nb = 0;
        results.forEach( (r) => { if(a === r)nb++ } ); 
        return { [a] : nb }
    })
}
```

if you want only the results to give to chartjs (as data) :

```
function results(answers,results){
    return answers.map( (a) => {
        var nb = 0;
        results.forEach( (r) => { if(a === r)nb++ } ); 
        return nb;
    })
}
```

here a working jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wanhe6rs/1/